# NextJS route not revalidating on-demand

Tags: next.js

I have a revalidate endpoint in my repo that is supposed to revalidate a group of pages when that endpoint is visited, however they (or at least one - the second in the list below) is apparently not working and revalidating the page data. Here is the code for the revalidation:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { revalidatePath } from 'next/cache';

export const runtime = 'edge';

export async function GET(request) {
  revalidatePath('/(something)/[...slug]');
  revalidatePath('/(something)/child/[slug]');
  return NextResponse.json({ revalidated: true, now: Date.now() });
}
```

So, when I visit `https://example.com/api/revalidate/pages/`, https://example.com/child/xyz is NOT having it's data revalidated. Is there something wrong with the way this is written, that is causing it to not work as expected?

Comment: Why do you need `/(something)` in your `revalidatePath` call?

Comment: @RobinThomas those are the folder groups that are part of the paths. are the folder groups not needed in the path there for revalidation to occur? I assumed it would need to follow the exact same naming as the the folder structure

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your project structure? I want to see if you have written the api paths correctly.